# Force a table to be displayed in a specific place

Tags: tables

Do you know how can I force my table to be displayed under question 3 and not be displayed under question 5 (it's currently displayed under question 5)? I've put `[htb]` but that doesn't seem to be working.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
...
Question 3 :
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \small % \footnotesize
\begin{tblr}{hlines={blue}, vlines={blue},
             colspec = {c X[0.8, l] X[1.2, c]},
             colsep  = 3pt,
             row{1}  = {c, font=\bfseries, fg=white, bg=blue},
             row{2-Z} = {bg=blue!10}
                 }
X   &   Vulnerabilities   \\
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    x1  
    &   \textbf{Vuln 1 :} my first parapgraph...    \\
    &   \textbf{Vuln 2 :} my first parapgraph...    \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
....
Question 5 :
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `table` if you do not want your tabular to float. Just use `center` or `minipage` and `captionof` (search around).  The `table` environment really means "add material that will be labelled as a table and will float around".

Comment: For an answer we need more context, If you replace `....` with some longer text or paragraph, table will be placed after `question 3`. The same will happen, if after `Question 3` you insert blank line.

Comment: Try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}\usepackage{tabularray}\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]

Question 3:
    \begin{table}[htb]
\begin{tblr}{hlines={blue}, vlines={blue},
             colspec={c Q[font=\bfseries,l] X[c]},
             colsep=3pt,
             row{1}={c, font=\bfseries, fg=white, bg=blue},
             row{2-Z}={bg=blue!10}}
X   & Vulnerabilities \\
\SetCell[r=2]{c} x1
    & Vuln 1: & my first parapgraph...  \\
    & Vuln 2: & my second parapgraph... \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
    
\lipsum[66]

Question 5:
\end{document}`

Comment: @Rmano it works simply by using `center`, thanks ! unfortunately the issue is closed you can't write it as an answer...